# How can I read an Excel file (xlsx) from my s3 bucket with Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kotlin

This question is similar than others made but for different languages

[Python: How to read and load an excel file from AWS S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439566/python-how-to-read-and-load-an-excel-file-from-aws-s3)

I am, unfortunately, not able to replicate this, I think the s3 client might be different.

At the moment I am able to connect to read from my s3 bucket, did the following:

```
val payload = s3.getObject("my-bucket', "my-file.xlsx")
```

This is returning an object of type `S3Object`.

As mentioned in other posts for python I should do

```
 val binary = payload['Body'].read()
```

but this is not available for me.

From payload I can see I have methods like `objectContent` but still doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how to do it?

I am using the AWS SDK 1.11

Answer (score 0):

You can get InputStream from S3Object, and then write it to a string for example:

```
 S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectInputStream = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(youS3Bucket, youFileName)).getObjectContent();
String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3ObjectInputStream))
.lines()
.parallel()
.collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

or to a file:

```
Files.copy(s3ObjectInputStream, Paths.get("myFile.xlsx"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```