# Read Excel file in AWS

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wanted to read an excel file in S3 from Glue.

Here's what I've done so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import awswrangler as wr
import io

ad_request_path = 's3://bucketname/key.xlsx'
df = wr.s3.read_excel(ad_request_path)
```

OR

```
bucket_name = 'bucketname'
object_key = 'key.xlsx'
    
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
data = obj['Body'].read()
workbook = open_workbook_xls(file_contents=data)

df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(data))
print(df)
```

I got this error message:

```
XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

Comment: See also: [Python: How to read and load an excel file from AWS S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53439566/174777)

Answer (score 2):

Managed to make it work. Just add `engine = 'openpyxl'`

```
import awswrangler as wr
import openpyxl

ad_request_path = 's3://bucketname/key.xlsx'
df = wr.s3.read_excel(ad_request_path, engine='openpyxl')
```